# How to fix 'JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '\' is found at position 1.' error in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I need to pass a JSON to stored procedure as a string and then convert that sting JSON using OPENJSON. The input parameter need be in string format and it contains \ scape characters.

The open JSON is available in SQL Server 2016, I have tried using OPENJSON without '\', it is perfectly working

**This code is working:**

```
DECLARE @test1 NVARCHAR(MAX)='{"name":"john","age":22,"class":"mca"}'
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@test1)
```

**This is not working:**

```
DECLARE @test2 NVARCHAR(MAX)='{\"name\":\"john smith\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}'
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@test2)
```

Comment: Why do you need that '\' ? just pass json value as is

Comment: If I do not convert it into string format, then I have a problem in the web service. The web service input value model will not validate the object. It needs to be in string format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the best approach, however:

```
DECLARE @test2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{\"name\":\"john smith\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}';
SELECT j.* 
FROM OPENJSON('{"t":"' + @test2 + '"}') t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.[value]) j
;
```

Another solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test2,'\\t','\t'),'\\r','\r'),'\\n','\n'),'\\f','\f'),'\\b','\b'),'\"','"'),'\\','\')) t
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vitaly, interesting solution. It is working but I wait a bit longer to see if I will  get a different solution

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my answer with another solution